# Accessing the key value in a selection field in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

I have a selection field with a key, value pair.  What I wish to do is when the user selects one of the choices in the selection field, an integer field gets the selection number and outputs it to the user.  How can I go about this in Odoo 8?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at their help documentation? http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, and I did not find what I was looking for.  Any suggestions? What I want is for the key to be retrieved and it will be outputted to the user.